# The 1000th element which is product of 2, 3, 5

Tags: algorithm

There is a sequence S.
All the elements in S is product of 2, 3, 5.
`S = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24 ...}`
How to get the 1000th element in this sequence efficiently?
I check each number from 1, but this method is too slow.

Comment: Create the sequence once, then return in O(1) ?

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers

Comment: @HappyCoder what if there is a memory limit?

Comment: Which limit prevents saving 1000 numbers?

Comment: 1000's number can be brute forced easily, but for larger number it would time out, so for the 1000th no the code is here : http://ideone.com/NJR1gV

Comment: It is a famous problem named Hamming Problem, google it and a lot of solution and explanation out there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A geometric approach**:

Let `s = 2^i . 3^j . 5^k`, where the triple `(i, j, k)` belongs to the first octant of a 3D state space.

Taking the logarithm,

```
ln(s) = i.ln(2) + j.ln(3) + k.ln(5)
```

so that in the state space the iso-`s` surfaces are planes, which intersect the first octant along a triangle. On the other hand, the feasible solutions are the nodes of a square grid.

If one wants to produce the `s`-values in increasing order, one can keep a list of the grid nodes closest to the current `s`-plane*, on its "greater than" side.

If I am right, to move from one `s`-value to the next, it suffices to discard the current `(i, j, k)` and replace it by the three triples `(i+1, j, k)`, `(i, j+1, k)` and `(i, j, k+1)`, unless they are already there, and pick the next smallest `s`.

An efficient implementation will be by storing the list as a binary tree with the `log(s)`-value as the key.

If you are asking for the first `N` values, you will explore a pyramidal volume of state-space of height `O(³√N)`, and base area `O(³√N²)`, which is the number of tree nodes, hence the spatial complexity. Every query in the tree will take `O(log(N))` comparisons (and `O(1)` operations to fetch the minimum), for a total of `O(N.log(N))`.

---

*More precisely, the list will contain all triples on the "greater than" side and such that no index can be decreased without getting on the other side of the plane.

---

Here is Python code that implements these ideas.

You will notice that the logarithms are converted to fixed point (7 decimals) to  avoid floating-point inaccuracies that could result in the `log(s)`-values not being found equal. This causes the `s` values being inexact in the last digits, but this does not matter as long as the ordering of the values is preserved. Recomputing the `s`-values from the indexes yields exact values.

```
import math
import bintrees

# Constants
ln2= round(10000000 * math.log(2))
ln3= round(10000000 * math.log(3))
ln5= round(10000000 * math.log(5))

# Initial list
t= bintrees.FastAVLTree()
t.insert(0, (0, 0, 0))

# Find the N first products
N= 100
for i in range(N):
    # Current s
    s= t.pop_min()
    print math.pow(2, s[1][0]) * math.pow(3, s[1][1]) * math.pow(5, s[1][2])

    # Update the list
    if not s[0] + ln2 in t:
        t.insert(s[0] + ln2, (s[1][0]+1, s[1][1], s[1][2]))
    if not s[0] + ln3 in t:
        t.insert(s[0] + ln3, (s[1][0], s[1][1]+1, s[1][2]))
    if not s[0] + ln5 in t:
        t.insert(s[0] + ln5, (s[1][0], s[1][1], s[1][2]+1))
```

The `100` first values are

```
   1     2     3     4     5     6     8     9    10    12 
  15    16    18    20    24    25    27    30    32    36 
  40    45    48    50    54    60    64    72    75    80 
  81    90    96   100   108   120   125   128   135   144 
 150   160   162   180   192   200   216   225   240   243 
 250   256   270   288   300   320   324   360   375   384 
 400   405   432   450   480   486   500   512   540   576 
 600   625   640   648   675   720   729   750   768   800 
 810   864   900   960   972  1000  1024  1080  1125  1152 
1200  1215  1250  1280  1296  1350  1440  1458  1500  1536
```

The plot of the number of tree nodes confirms the `O(³√N²)` spatial behavior.
[image]

---

**Update**:

When there is no risk of overflow, a much simpler version (not using logarithms) is possible:

```
import math
import bintrees

# Initial list
t= bintrees.FastAVLTree()
t[1]= None

# Find the N first products
N= 100
for i in range(N):
    # Current s
    (s, r)= t.pop_min()
    print s

    # Update the list
    t[2 * s]= None
    t[3 * s]= None
    t[5 * s]= None
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you just have to generate each i<sup>th</sup> number consecutively. Let's call the set {2, 3, 5} to be Z. At i<sup>th</sup> iteration, assume you have all (i-1) of the values generated in the previous iteration. While generating the next one, what you basically have to do is trying all the elements in Z and for each of them generating **the least element they can form that is larger than the element generated at (i-1)<sup>th</sup> iteration. Then, you simply consider the smallest one among them as the i<sup>th</sup> value. A simple and not so efficient implementation is given below.

```
def generate_simple(N, Z):
    generated = [1]
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        minFound = -1
        minElem = -1
        for j in range(0, len(Z)):
            for k in range(0, len(generated)):
                candidateVal = Z[j] * generated[k]
                if candidateVal > generated[-1]:
                    if minFound == -1 or minFound > candidateVal:
                        minFound = candidateVal
                        minElem = j
                    break
        generated.append(minFound)
    return generated[-1]
```

As you may observe, this approach has a time complexity of **O(N<sup>2</sup> * |Z|)**. An improvement in terms of efficiency would be to store where we left off scanning in the array of generated values for each element in a second array, indicesToStart. Then, for each element we would only scan all N values of the array *generated* for once(i.e. **all through the algorithm**), which means the time complexity after such an improvement would be **O(N * |Z|)**.

A simple implementation of the improvement based on the simple version provided above, is given below.

```
def generate_improved(N, Z):
    generated = [1]
    indicesToStart = [0] * len(Z)
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        minFound = -1
        minElem = -1
        for j in range(0, len(Z)):
            for k in range(indicesToStart[j], len(generated)):
                candidateVal = Z[j] * generated[k]
                if candidateVal > generated[-1]:
                    if minFound == -1 or minFound > candidateVal:
                        minFound = candidateVal
                        minElem = j
                    break
                indicesToStart[j] += 1
        generated.append(minFound)
        indicesToStart[minElem] += 1
    return generated[-1]
```

If you have a hard time understanding how complexity decreases with this algorithm, try looking into the difference in time complexity of any graph traversal algorithm when an adjacency list is used, and when an adjacency matrix is used. The improvement adjacency lists help achieve is almost exactly the same kind of improvement we get here. In a nutshell, you have an index for each element and instead of starting to scan from the beginning you **continue** from wherever you left the last time you scanned the *generated* array for that element. Consequently, even though there are N iterations in the algorithm(i.e. the outermost loop) the overall number of operations you make is **O(N * |Z|)**.

**Important Note:** All the code above is a simple implementation for demonstration purposes, and you should consider it just as a pseudocode you can test. While implementing this in real life, based on the programming language you choose to use, you will have to consider issues like integer overflow when computing *candidateVal*.